# Probability there is no president

Tags: probability, voting-theory

I know you may decide my question is off-topic but I will give it a try:
I read this in a Facebook group, posted by a person who claims to be a mathematician.

In the US presidential elections, for a candidate to be elected president, he must receive 270 of the 538 electoral votes. What is the probability that no president is elected?

> Although I am not very familiar with the electoral system in US, I replied to this guy that it is not a matter of probabilities, because the election of each elector is not a random event. We vote for them and the outcome depends on our vote.

> Did I reply correctly, or there is some other approach which I am missing? Thank you very much!

Comment: Well...it becomes a mater of probability when you must estimate vote totals (as of course we must, at this point).  You could, say, take polling data and assume that the actual vote will have that as a mean, but have some noise, up to, say, the margin of error in the poll.  And I'm sure you can come up with some other models.  But anythinng one says will be very model dependent.

Comment: There is a large amount of missing information here... including but not limited to the number of candidates, the probability for each of the electoral votes to be put towards a particular candidate, and the independency of the voting results for each of the electoral votes.  It is feasible that if a third party gained enough popularity that no individual candidate receives the required $270$ votes (*e.g. 265-265-8*), however historically a third party has not yet ever had enough popularity to affect things to this degree.

Comment: Probabilities can also represent subjective expectations of events you do not have complete knowledge of. Coin tosses are essentially deterministic functions of the tossing, but you cannot usually know the parameters in enough detail to predict how the coin will land. Electors are voted for, but since nobody knows for sure how the votes will be cast, they are functionally random

Comment: As we are looking at a system with uncertainty, what we can do is model the possibilities as a system of random variables, and assign a probability based on that model.  We can debate to the end of the earth whether the assumptions of the model are correct (how should the distributions of these random variables be determined), and whether the model is an accurate representation of reality.  But, this is fundamental to the nature of applied mathematics.

Comment: Now... as for the reality of the situation, a president will be elected one way or another even if not as a direct result of the electoral college.  It winds up going to the House of Representatives, but the specifics of all of that are getting quite off topic.  Look up the election of John Quincy Adams.

Comment: Maybe he means what's the probability each candidate gets 269 electors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for the number of ways to get 269 electoral votes, see [Generating Functions and the Electoral College](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0746834246866.di020799.02p0714z.pdf), which is based on the apportionment from 2000 U.S. Census data and makes the simplifying assumption that Maine and Nebraska are winner-take-all.